# Implement mixins in TypeScript without using any type

Tags: typescript, mixins

I am wrangling with this mixin-creating TypeScript code:

```
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: Function, constructors: Function[]) {
    //Copies methods
    constructors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach((name) => {
        Object.defineProperty(
          derivedCtor.prototype,
          name,
          Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name) ||
            Object.create(null)
        );
      });
    });
    //Copies properties
    constructors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
      let empty = new baseCtor();
      Object.keys(empty).forEach((name) => {
        Object.defineProperty(
          derivedCtor.prototype,
          name,
          Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(empty, name) ||
            Object.create(null)
        );
      });
    });
  }
```

It does not compile, complaining about this row: `let empty = new baseCtor();`: `TS2351: This expression is not constructable. Type 'Function' has no construct signatures.`. I know that this can be fixed by swapping both `Function` type references in the 1st row with `any`, but I'm trying to live my life without `any`, as it often is a sloppy way to tell TypeScript to shut up.

Is there a way to implement this code without using `any`?

Comment: `Function` isn't known to be constructable, while, say, `new () => object` or `{new(): object}` is.  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/vW4M4w) work for your use case? If so I'll write up an answer when I get a chance. If not, please elaborate in the question text with relevant examples.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I added `declare type ctorType = new() => object;` in the module, and then use `ctorType` instead of `Function`. But what is the difference in comparison with `{new(): object}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Function` is a very wide type and includes any function, including ones which cannot be called via `new`.  Therefore the compiler is complaining that `Function` is not constuctible.  The solution is therefore to use a type which *is* known to have a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures).  In TypeScript, such a signature is represented by prepending the keyword `new` to a function signature:

```
type NewableFunctionSyntax = new () => object;
type NewableMethodSyntax = { new(): object };
```

Those types both represent a constructor that accepts no arguments and produces an instance of type assignable `object`.  Note that while those syntaxes are different, they are essentially the same.  (To see this, note that the compiler allows you to declare a `var` multiple times but will complain if you annotate it with different types.  The fact that the following compiles with no error,

```
var someCtor: NewableFunctionSyntax;
var someCtor: NewableMethodSyntax; // no error
```

is an indication that the compiler treats `NewableFunctionSyntax` and `NewableMethodSyntax` as essentially interchangeable.)

---

By changing `Function` to one of these, your code now compiles with no errors:

```
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: { new(): object }, constructors: { new(): object }[]) {
    //Copies methods
    constructors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach((name) => {
            Object.defineProperty(
                derivedCtor.prototype,
                name,
                Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name) ||
                Object.create(null)
            );
        });
    });
    //Copies properties
    constructors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
        let empty = new baseCtor();
        Object.keys(empty).forEach((name) => {
            Object.defineProperty(
                derivedCtor.prototype,
                name,
                Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(empty, name) ||
                Object.create(null)
            );
        });
    });
}
```

---

Let's test out calling `applyMixins()` to make sure we understand what `{new(): object}` does and does not match:

```
class Works {
    x = 1;
    constructor() { }
}
applyMixins(Works, []); // okay
```

`Works` is fine because it is a class constructor which takes no parameters.

```
class CtorRequiresArg {
    y: string;
    constructor(y: string) { this.y = y; }
}

applyMixins(CtorRequiresArg, []); // error!
// -------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'new (y: string) => CtorRequiresArg' 
// is not assignable to type 'new () => object'
```

`CtorRequiresArg` fails because you have to pass a `string` argument when you construct it, like `new CtorRequiresArg("hello")`... but `applyMixins()` only accepts constructors that can be called without any arguments.

And finally:

```
function NotACtor() { }

applyMixins(NotACtor, []); // error!
// -------> ~~~~~~~~
// Type '() => void' provides no match 
// for the signature 'new (): object'
```

`NotACtor` fails because it is not considered constructible.  This may be surprising because at runtime nothing will stop you from calling `new NotACtor()`, but it is the compiler's opinion that if you wanted a class constructor you would be using `class` notation in `.ts` files... even when targeting an ES5 runtime, since TypeScript will down-level it for you automatically.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#2310](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2310) for more information)

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDuBDARgGwgMQK4DsDGwAlgPY4DKIOwiAHlALxQ4JQAUAlAwHxTHIBWEAgG4AsAChQkWAhToAshGAALYgBMKVWgygBvJgg4AuXgKHAoAXzHiJAN0QAnKAGdiAWwgBhYMUcm4JDRMXAISckpqGhsHZzdPHz8A2WDFFXVNKOEoAHocpmIoCEdHPwl4719nRhwsVFQAQglm8QAzUKJSKEQwMFQQeUIaQhwXVjViwjsINUT-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-gAdT8Vc-nxQk6EYABGRcth2CF2w4BZLAkfjxB6PoBiGEYxjoxwGM2B4C3eXhV0QEAKKolw-jmAAlCAAEcsEIRxfgAQUcClj0JEATFbEYKQ4ltuMDCzXD2aynigFRCBhKdGBAbJBMEiRhP6QZhlGVhNJ0vSDJcYyKRkx5sjyIoSj8JpxESgBaTKsvSngAD98oKwqiokRKABVzSgAByGdWEcqycApI9wt0-SjJMyryLS-IPIKCxqMICkJWCNzCgFKqaqPK5zEqlp2nwTocFgU1DPnVz-KE3ogrE0KYGWuY4rkxLilKRxUoy7LMryor8pK-JyukSreNxKA7GIQg1A6k07HemscEKdx02RTrEq7NzlGgFwBolYAsAM8aWGWKaCEqoA)

Comment: Does there exist a type declaration that captures any constuctible, no only constuctibles with specific signatures? I tried with `new(...args: unknown[]) => object;`, but that does not allow constructors with specificly typed parameters. With `new(...args: any[]) => object;` the compiler doesn't complain any more, but then we are using reference `any` that defies the purpose of my question.